# logstash Persistent queue working slow in logstash-8.11.3

Tags: logstash, elk

Persistent queue in logstash 8.3.3 is working fine as expected. but same config is not working as expected in logtash-8.7.3 and 8.11.3 and observed slowness in accepting events from filebeat.

here is the persisted queue setting in logstash.yml:

```
pipeline.batch.size: 750
queue.type: persisted
queue.max_bytes: 2.5g
queue.page_capacity: 500mb
pipeline.batch.delay: 1
```

please help analyzing this. is anything missed in config in higher version.